# Filter results in a Lookup Filter Field's search results

Tags: case, validation-rule, contact, search, checkbox

1. Custom Contact Field "Active" = Data type Checkbox.
2. "Active" is filterable in Contact Search Layouts.
3. If "Active" which is only a checkbox, & is a filter option in the Case>Contact Name>Lookup, then Is there a way to create a validation rule, so that the user, does not have to select: Active: True?
4. The goal is to stop Contacts with the the checkbox set to "Inactive" from appearing in the search result. Which can currently only be achieved from applying filters.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a filter for the Contact Name lookup field, which will limit the search results to active users.

Under settings > Case edit the Contact Name lookup field, and a filter like this:

[image]

Make sure to activate the filter rule!

[image]

Now, when you're searching for a contact from the lookup, you'll only see active users initially.  There's a link to show more filters (if any fields have been added to the layout), but the "inactive = false" filter will be applied by default.

Comment: OMG THAT WORKED!!!!! DUDE! I love you <3. Thank you sir, thank you very much!

Comment: Hehehe.  I knew we'd get there eventually.  No problem.